# Is "Sonic Colors Ultimate" 0+ or 7+? Don't understand the big difference between the two rating systems

Tags: esrb, sonic-colors-ultimate

Is "Sonic Colors Ultimate" 0+ or 7+? Don't understand the big difference between platforms and rating systems.
Sure there are two different rating systems, USA and Europe.

But the difference is way too big, can't explain this big difference.
Can anyone give me details?

Can I generally take the lower number for different rating systems?

Sony:

[image]

Microsoft:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Sure there are two different rating systems*" That's the answer.

ESRB rated this game E(stands for Everyone), because there is no lower rate that is currently in use (there once was, eC, stands for Early Childhood).

PEGI rated this game 7+, since it contains a little bit of cartoon violence (in case if you didn't know, Minecraft is also rated 7+). Just FYI: there is 3+ rating in ESRB.

While those twos are most popular rating system, there is other organization that rated this game for everyone or suitable for children, such as [CERO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Entertainment_Rating_Organization)(they've rated A, which stands for All Ages), [USK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unterhaltungssoftware_Selbstkontrolle)(rated 6+), etc...

In conclusion... it's your choice to let your toddlers play which games. If you believe your toddlers can take a little bit of violent scene, then Sonic colors sure is a good start. If you don't, then, go get some other game that is rated 3+ in PEGI.